# Apache Flink; Determine Window Boundary Timestamps

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Apache Flink, when processing the result of an aggregation, I need to know the timestamp (process time) of the start of a tumbling window.  Is there a way to get this timestamp?  Are window boundaries or is the watermark exposed tot he AggregationFunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with your `AggregateFunction`, you have the option to specify a `WindowFunction`.

According to the documentation you can do the following:

```java
stream.
.keyBy()
.window()
.aggregate(new AverageAggregate(), new WindowFunctionTest());


public static class WindowFunctionTest implements WindowFunction<..., ..., 
    Tuple, TimeWindow> {
    public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<...> input, 
    Collector<...> out) {
        long windowStartTime = window.getStart();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question as I asked.  Though, I should have clarified that I'm looking for the timestamp as I write to the sink.

Also, FYI:  I looks like `ProcessWindowFunction` is the new preferred way and WindowFunction will be deprecated:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/

Comment: Pleasure. Also, I have to mention that window start and end are related to the time notion that you're working with.

Comment: Turns out that the timestamps in the SinkWriter.Context are not related to the window time stamps (I'm not sure what the timestamps are for).  I ended up having to use a ProcessWindowFunction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [SinkWriter.Context](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/connector/sink2/SinkWriter.Context.html) in the [ElementConverter](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/base/sink/writer/ElementConverter.html) has the window and watermark timestamp.  I only need the timestamps when writing to the sink, so this is sufficient for me.